# an abstract class inherits another abstract class issue

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, abstract-class, encapsulation

I have an inheritance schema like below:

```
public abstract class BaseAttachment
{
    public abstract string GetName();
}

public abstract class BaseFileAttachment:BaseAttachment
{
    public abstract string GetName();
}

public class ExchangeFileAttachment:BaseFileAttachment
{
    string name;
    public override string GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I basically want to call GetName() method of the ExchangeFileAttachment class; However, the above declaration is wrong. Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is your intent to provide a completely new `GetName` method on `BaseFileAttachment` that _hides_ `BaseAttachment.GetName`? If not, just omit the redeclaration.

Comment: Why is `ExchangeFileAttachment` declared `abstract`?

Comment: "However, the above declaration is wrong" You should really provide more details in your questions.  Does it not compile?  Is it not doing what you desire?  If so, what are the errors or undesirable behavior?

Comment: @Servy For what it's worth this at least compiles fine, so there's that.  I think it'd be pretty awesome to have some more detail though, for sure.

Comment: @YYY It's still possible for his problem to be that his project isn't compiling, which would tell us that his problem is in code that's not posted, or that he changed something when posting the code.

Comment: @Servy Er, whoops!  Actually there is a compilation error in the code as is.  The inherited abstract member hiding will cause the compiler to fail the build.  I thought that was just my Resharper configuration flagging it as an error until I checked just now.

Comment: i forgot to check. ExchangeFileAttachment class is not abstract. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should an abstract class implement an abstract method of an abstract base class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271682/why-should-an-abstract-class-implement-an-abstract-method-of-an-abstract-base-cl). Though title is misleading, the question is the same..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The two immediate problems I see is that your final `ExchangeFileAttachment` class is declared `abstract`, so you'll never be able to instantiate it.  Unless you have another level of inheritance you are not showing us, calling it will not be possible - there's no way to access it. The other problem is that `BaseFileAttachment` has a property that is hiding the `GetName()` in `BaseAttachment`.  In the structure you are showing us, it is redundant and can be omitted.  So, the 'corrected' code would look more like:

```
public abstract class BaseAttachment
{
    public abstract string GetName();
}

public abstract class BaseFileAttachment : BaseAttachment
{
}

public class ExchangeFileAttachment : BaseFileAttachment
{
    string name;
    public override string GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I put corrected in quotes because this use-case still does not make a ton of sense so I'm hoping you can give more information, or this makes a lot more sense on your end.

Comment: This code example helped my answer a completely different question!

Answer (score 11):

Just remove the redeclaration from `BaseFileAttachment`:

```
public abstract class BaseFileAttachment : BaseAttachment
{
}
```

`BaseFileAttachment` already inherits the abstract `GetName` declaration from `BaseAttachment`.  If you really want to mention it again in `BaseFileAttachment`, use the `override` keyword:

```
public abstract class BaseFileAttachment : BaseAttachment
{
    public override abstract string GetName(); // that's fine as well
}
```